# Lightning:unsavedChanges not working in community page

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have a component in community and it has a textbox and a cancel button. I want to show a modal when user clicks on cancel after updating textbox. But I am not getting the modal.

Component

```
<aura:component  implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes">
<aura:attribute name="firstName" type="String" />
<lightning:unsavedChanges aura:id="unsaved"
                          onsave="{!c.handleSave}"
                          ondiscard="{!c.handleDiscard}" />
<lightning:input type="text" value="{!v.lastName}" onchange="{!c.handlechange}"/>
<lightning:button aura:id="cancel" label="CANCEL" onclick="{! c.handleCancelClick }"/>
```

controller

```
handlechange: function(component, event, helper) {
    var unsaved = component.find("unsaved");
    unsaved.setUnsavedChanges(true, { label: 'My component name' });
},
handleCancelClick: function(component, event, helper) {
    window.location.href = 'https://www.google.com/';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The component is **not** supported in Community. Refer to the Experience section in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:unsavedChanges/documentation) where the only supported experience listed is **Lightning Experience**.

You will need to write some custom code/logic to achieve what you need here.